# For creating click-able buttons on header div which tags should I use?

Tags: css, html

I want add buttons on top of a div (like main menu for most websites). Yesterday I created the buttons using different div tag for each button and adding lots of margins but the end result wasn't working good on internet explorer so I I decided to use a different method. DL tags also didn't work well, now I tried span tags but still I can't position them where I want. The margins doesn't respond and I don't know what to do.
P.S: The header div also have two images on the left and I want the buttons to be positioned on the right.

Comment: Why not use `ul` and `li` tags? We can't provide specific help because you've given us no clue at all as to what exactly went wrong, what didn't work, what happened or what you wanted it to look like in the first place.

Comment: use `<ul>` and `<li>` tags then display them as inline-block

Comment: @Vector The problem is positioning. I can't position them well on top of that div, everytime they interfere with the images and things get messy. I hope this explain

Comment: Please have a look at this HTML: <div id="header"><div id="logo"><img src="images/logo1.png"/><div id="slogan"><img src="images/slogan.png"/></div></div> Now I want to add three buttons that won't effect the images position and would be exactly on the right side of the header div

Comment: put them all inside it's own `<div>` container called `nav` to keep things neat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For formatting / styling, the tags are inconsequential - it really depends what you want to do with them in terms of look/feel, because most of the commonly used tags (div, span, li, etc) have different "default" properties.

Using CSS, you can make any of those elements look however you want - they are all acceptable options from a purely stylistic point of view.  Unfortunately, there will often be a discrepancy in your styles when viewed in internet explorer - the bane of many front-end developer's existence - but you can fix internet explorer issues with some investigation of the issues & the use conditional styles.

**a couple of starting points on those topics:**

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them/

From a **semantic** point of view, in html5 markup it's generally recommended to build your main menu using a **nav** tag to indicate that you're building a top-level site navigation structure.  Generally speaking, **nav** tags wrap a **ul**, which in turn wraps a series of **li**'s.

```
<nav id="main-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pageX">Page X</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

more information is available here: http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/

Comment: if you're using HTML5, use NAV - if not, don't use div... just use ul with li's... Unless you've got a special styling circumstance which you haven't told us about the div class menu wrapper is unnecessary.  The NAV is only there for semantic reasons - That said, there's no "one last answer" to this question... use whatever makes best sense for your situation.

Comment: great, thanks. I used the nav tags (first time). and how do I create a bigger distance between the li tags?

Comment: you can use margin & padding on the LI tags or the A elements contained within to space them out more.  There are a few more nuances of this question that are outside of the scope of your oringinal question however.  quick version:  A is usually inline element.  but it's the "clickable" one.  if you add margin/padding to the LI, the clickable area of the A tag remains only on the text.  If you want to have a button with a wider click-area, you need to make the "A" elements block level (display:block) and increase the padding around them.  If you're using chrome, press f12 and play w/dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Create an outer wrapper

```
<div class="menu-wrapper">
</div>
```

As commented above use ul and li for your menu. This is kind of a standard almost or at least what is most often used. inside the above wrapper use the following unordered list with your relevant links.

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
    <li><a>About</a></li>
</ul>
```

For the styling and since you have images in your header (you could wrap them in a div and float them as well or +1 for using some scaffolding grid such as in Twitter Bootstrap) you'll want to float the menu wrapper. You could also just float over the ul however this is particularly how I like to do it.

```
div.menu-wrapper { float: right; }
ul.menu li { display:-moz-inline-stack; display:inline-block;zoom:1;*display:inline;}
ul.menu li a { display:block; padding: 6px 12px; }
ul.menu li a:hover { /* some nice hover style here */}
```

The above should get you going in the correct direction. In the above the li style is using a cross browser inline-block. you can also just float it if you wish.

By the way I style me css rather verbose some don't like that so feel free to name each element and style accordingly. This is just how I prefer it in my editor as it auto indents etc.